# Using PhilJay / MPAndroidChart, How do I take a screenshot of the entire chart and not just what's visible?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How do I get a bitmap of the entire chart and not just what's visible? I tried the chart.getChartBitmap(); and chart.saveToGallery("filename"); Whilst both of them work, they only capture what's visible to the user. I wish to capture the entire chart regardless of its visibility to the user. Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer will be bashed. But it worked for me. I just figured it out.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart
                        android:id="@+id/combinedChartBroodingGrowing"
                        android:layout_width="3000dp"
                        android:layout_height="1000dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Unfortunately you'll need to specify the layout_width and layout_height explicitly in order for this to work(You'll need to play around and decide what's best for you. Also, please note: I haven't checked for any side effects. Use with discretion. I'm so sorry!). Also make sure `setVisibleXRangeMaximum()` is not set. And then call `saveToGallery()` as usual. You'll see the entire chart saved to gallery. :)